# FatFractal grabBagAdd() -- Error 400: Cannot add NULL items to a object's grab bag

Tags: web-applications, custom-backend

I am getting an error when calling the grabBagAdd() method using the FatFractal JavaScript (HTML5) SDK. For this particular problem, my data model is simple, and only involves two object types: a custom Team object and the default FFUser object.

Relevant FFDL Declarations:

```
CREATE OBJECTTYPE FFUser (userName STRING, firstName STRING, lastName STRING, email STRING, active BOOLEAN, authDomain STRING, groups GRABBAG /FFUserGroup, notif_ids GRABBAG /FFNotificationID)
CREATE OBJECTTYPE Team (teamName STRING, members GRABBAG /FFUser)

CREATE COLLECTION /FFUser OBJECTTYPE FFUser
CREATE COLLECTION /Teams OBJECTTYPE Team
```

JS Object Declarations:

```
function Team(data){
    if(data){
        this.clazz = data.clazz;
        this.guid = data.guid;
        this.teamName = data.teamName;
    }
    else{
        this.clazz = "Team";
        this.guid = null;
        this.teamName = null;
    }
    return this;
}

function FFUser(data){
    if(data){
        this.clazz = data.clazz;
        this.userName = data.userName;
        this.firstName = data.firstName;
        this.lastName = data.lastName;
        this.email = data.email;
        this.active = data.active;
        this.guid = data.guid;
    }
    else{
        this.clazz = "FFUser";
        this.userName = null;
        this.firstName = null;
        this.lastName = null;
        this.email = null;
        this.active = null;
        this.guid = null;
    }
    return this;
}
```

I'm simply attempting to add an FFUser to a selected Team's members grab bag. I am using KnockoutJS bindings to display my web app's data and KnockoutJS observables to store the data locally. The pertinent steps in the use case generating the error are as follows:

Pull Teams from my app's back-end after user logs in. Below, `self.teams` is an observable array which is bound to an HTML select menu.

```
    function loadTeams() {
        ff.getArrayFromUri("/ff/resources/Teams",function(loadedTeams) {
            if(loadedTeams.length > 0) {
                for(var i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {
                    var team = new Team(loadedTeams[i]);
                    self.teams.push(team);
                }
            }
            else console.log("No teams to load!");
        },function(statusCode,responseText) {
            alert(JSON.parse(responseText).statusMessage);
        });
    };
```

The user selects a team from the select menu and enters a username to add as a team member. Upon submission, the grabBagAdd() is executed. Below, `self.selectedTeam` is an observable bound to the value of the select menu and contains one of the Team objects from `self.teams`. Also, `self.addMemberEmail` is an observable bound to the value of the username input box.

```
    self.addMember = function() {
        if(self.addMemberEmail()) {
            ff.getObjFromUri("/ff/resources/FFUser/(userName eq '" + self.addMemberEmail() + "')",function(user) {
                if(user){
                    var member = new FFUser(user);
                    ff.grabBagAdd(member,self.selectedTeam(),"members",function() {
                        console.log("Added member to grabbag!");
                    },function(statusCode,responseText) {
                        alert(JSON.parse(responseText).statusMessage);
                    });         
                }
                else alert("No users found with the provided username.");
            },function(statusCode,responseText) {
                alert(JSON.parse(responseText).statusMessage);
            });
        }
        else alert("Must provide member email.");
    };
```

FatFractal returns a `400: Bad Request` error as follows:

```
FatFractal.handleGrabBagRequest 400, {"result":null,"statusMessage":"Cannot add NULL items to a object's grab bag"}
```

Not sure what to make of the error. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `grabBagAdd` function takes `ffUrl`s, not the objects themselves, as the first two arguments. So, try the following:

```
ff.grabBagAdd(member.ffUrl, self.selectedTeam().ffUrl, "members", ...
```

From your question, it's not completely clear that `self.selectedTeam()` will return an object with metadata, but anyway you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks, just added an ffUrl attribute to my JS objects, and worked perfectly!